# rails newでpostgresqlの場合エラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

railsでDBにPostgreSQLを指定してプロジェクトを作成しましたが、エラーが発生し `bundle install` できません。恐れ入りますが、どなたかご教授頂ければと存じます。

※ `brew install postgresql` を実行した場合は Warning: postgresql-9.6.3 already installed と表示されるのでPostgreSQLはインストール済みです。パスの問題なのでしょうか？

#### 手順

1. `rails new hoge -d postgresql`
2. Gemfileへgem 'pg'を追加
3. `bundle install` を実行
4. エラー発生

エラー内容

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/4v/dsv8p_992w1f1f5bjqfwrp2h0000gn/T/bundler20170603-10893-150s2dspg-0.20.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/4v/dsv8p_992w1f1f5bjqfwrp2h0000gn/T/bundler20170603-10893-150s2dspg-0.20.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext/gem_make.out
    
An error occurred while installing pg (0.20.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.20.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は不明なのですが、以下の記事を参照して解決できました。

[Mavericks でgem install pgしてNo pg_configになるとき](http://qiita.com/satton_maroyaka/items/e142b7590eec1a649e8b)

Answer (score 0):

database.ymlの設定でpostgresqlの記述はありますでしょうか？